# Count occurrences based on user defined criteria across multiple columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to write a query to generate a frequency table. Currently I am working on Amazon redshift database. I have generated a table that looks like below :

```
user_id   user_label     code1  code2  code_3  date    
------   -----------    -----  -----  ------  -------
1        x              a      b      c       01-01
1        x              a      d      c       01-01
1        x              a      b      c       01-02
1        y              a      c      d       01-01
2        x              a      b      d       01-01
```

etc

The rule to count occurrences is if two rows have the same id and date ,then repeated codes should only be counted once. 
For example, for the first two rows the frequency table should be :

```
user_id      user_label   a   b   c   d 
--------     -----------  --  --  --  -- 
1            x            1   1   1   1
```

Because even though there are two instances of a and c each, but they happen on the same date so should only be counted once and I need do this for every unique combination of user_id + user_label

Then after processing the third row , the frequency table should be :

```
user_id      user_label   a   b   c   d 
--------     -----------  --  --  --  -- 
1            x            2   2   2   1
```

Because third row has different date and thus the count for a,b,c should increase by 1

In the end, for the sample table given above, the desired result should be

```
user_id      user_label   a   b   c   d 
--------     -----------  --  --  --  -- 
1            x            2   2   2   1
1            y            1   1   1   0
2            x            1   1   0   1
```

I know I should have put what I have tried so far , but really I don't know where to get started. 
This is not a homework problem and any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on your question, I changed the tag to amazon-redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
select user_id, user_label,
       count(distinct case when 'a' in (code1, code2, code3) then date end) as a,
       count(distinct case when 'b' in (code1, code2, code3) then date end) as b,
       count(distinct case when 'c' in (code1, code2, code3) then date end) as c,
       count(distinct case when 'd' in (code1, code2, code3) then date end) as d
from t
group by user_id, user_label
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you so much for your quick reply. I will accept your answer 
Just one more follow up question , my table currently has thousands of columns, I don't think it is practical to add each one in the select statement, is there any way make this work with thousands or tens of thousands of columns ?

Comment: @ZhezhongJiang . . . Not without writing a long query.  Storing data horizontally introduces this problem.  It is better to put repeated values in rows, not columns.

Comment: So if I do change the table to store repeated values in rows , how can I generate the frequency table as desired ? How would you approach the problem if you don't mind me asking.... I am just really stuck

Comment: @ZhezhongJiang . . . That would be a new question and should be asked as a question, not a comment.